# How to use infile.open(file_nameI.c_str());

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++03

So I have this code that is coming back with

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&)'
```

and

```
error: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'
```

and im pretty sure this is because the dumb compiler my professor has me use is c++ 03.

I'm also pretty sure that I should use infile.open(file_nameI.c_str()); to fix this, but I cant figure out how.

```
int main()
{
    ofstream outfile;
    ifstream infile; 

    std::string line, file_nameI, file_nameO, name, Id;

    float  hworkgrade, grade1;
    int deductions;

    cout << "Please enter name of input file:  ";
    cin >> file_nameI;
    infile.open(file_nameI);
    if ( !infile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open input file \n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter name of output file:  ";
    cin >> file_nameO;
    outfile.open(file_nameO);
    if ( !outfile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open output file \n";
        return 0;
    }

    while (getline (infile, line))
    {
        infile.open(file_nameI.c_str());
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> name >> Id;
        cout<< name << " " << Id;
        hworkgrade = CalHworkGrade(grade1, infile);
        printRecord(name, Id, outfile);
        cin.ignore();
    }
    while(!infile.eof());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you used it right in the while loop.  Why did you not change it outside the while loop?  Also what is the purpose of opening it in the while loop when you opened it before the while loop?

Comment: @NathanOliver I've tried it everywhere, nothing has worked. This just happened to be my last guess before asking for help.

Comment: Do you see the line `infile.open(file_nameI);` that the compiler is telling you is wrong? There is the place. (And remove it from the while loop. And remove the `while(!infile.eof());` that you left in there when you removed the `do`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo No more errors! Except the program fails to open the file. Prints "could not open input file"

Comment: If the file is not opening, that means 2 things: either the file does not exist, or it is not in the correct directory. Try specifying the directory when you input the file name.

Comment: I did specify the directory and th file opened before I made this change it just didnt output correctly